# How can I create a firewalld rule that allow SSH connection only from a specific IP address?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall, firewalld

I am not a system engineer or a network expert (I am more a software developer) and I have the following problem that I have to solve related IPTABLES firewall.

I have n Linux machines that must accept SSH connection only from another specific machine. I have to set a firewalld firewall rule that implement this behavior. Is this the following rule correct?

```
<rule family="ipv4">
  <source address="192.168.1.100/32"/>
  <service name="ssh"/>
  <accept/>
</rule>
```

Or in case what could be the correct rule for this behavior?